# Call block inside a block objective c

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I wish to call Block B on completion of Block A (`isInsertSuccess` returns `YES`). Can someone help me using the code below? Thank you.

Block A

```
[userServiceInstance insertDataOnSuccess:^
 {
    if (![userServiceInstance isInsertSuccess]) {
                 NSLog(@“Insert is successful”);
    }
 }];
```

Block B

```
[PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status){
    NSLog(@“This is the status, %ld”, status);
}];
```

Comment: Did you try putting block B inside the `if` statement of block A? It's unclear what issue you are having.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Block B is not triggered when i put it inside Block A. But when i put block B outside the block it works as expected.

Comment: Your `if` statement is wrong. Get rid of the `!`. Otherwise the log will only show when `isInsertSuccess` is `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
[userServiceInstance insertDataOnSuccess:^{
   if (![userServiceInstance isInsertSuccess]) {
       NSLog(@“Insert is successful”);
       [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status){
           NSLog(@“This is the status, %ld”, status);
       }];
   }
}];
```

Comment: Block B is not getting triggered. When i put it outside the block, it works as expected.

Comment: Then either: A) block A is never getting called or B) or your condition in the if is resulting in `NO` Are you sure you didn't mean to do [userServiceInstance isInsertSuccess] (without the !)? Your log seems to indicate success but your if looks to be doing the opposite.

Comment: Yes i even remove the entire if statement for testing. But no still luck. Strange. Would this count as recursive? There appears to be a format im just not sure of it.

Comment: Then Block A is never getting called so that's your problem.You haven't provided enough information to know _why_ this is happening however. No, this is not recursive.

Comment: In my actual code i have a NSLog before the if statement in block A and its getting printed. Thus im pretty sure the block is getting triggered.

Comment: Putting block B in block A shouldn't affect block A. You should post the code for `insertDataOnSuccess:` to be sure though.

Comment: After trying so many times and with all the logging, i decided to run block B outside block A. Not really sure why block B is not triggered. Thanks @Lance appreciate your help.